# List of MD /Raid/LVM (Devices) = How to mount them without any further information available?

Tags: linux, mount

I do not have much skills in linux and installed a system two years ago that I now had to reboot, but it seems I did not automate everything with start-scripts...

My Problem: I miss some mountpoints. I have a list of my raids (excerpt:)

```
md3 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda6[0] sdb6[1]
      97659008 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md4 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sda7[0] sdb7[1]
      250099776 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

and it seems md3 and md4 are NOT mounted. However i do NOT have any entries for them fstab file.

What should I do next. I do NOT know which filesystem they have (most likely ext3).

=>Can I savely try to mount them with (`mount -t ext3 /dev/md3 /mnt/mymntpoint`) or will the lead to corrupted data, in case they are not ext3?

What should I do next (based on the information given above). The goal is to remount these Devices again, but I do not know anything about them anymore...

Thank you very much Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `fdisk -l` to see the FS they have installed

then mount them accordingly